# I put 4 gigs of RAM into a new server, why does it say I have only 3462960k RAM?

Tags: memory

I put 4 gigs of RAM into a server, but when I look at the command line why does it say I have only 3462960k RAM?

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:        3462960 kB

[root@localhost ~]# free
             total       
Mem:       3462960  

[root@localhost ~]# top
Mem:   3462960k total...
```

Comment: Perhaps MemTotal doesn't mean what you think it does http://www.redhat.com/advice/tips/meminfo.html or you MB isn't seeing all the RAM.

Comment: You mistakenly installed a 32-bit OS?

Comment: 4gb into a NEW server? Is that an exersice is in "how little memory can I put into servers"? I mean, I am having computers with low memory here - calculation nodes for a HPC cluster - and we allocate 1gb/core and guess what - there are no quad core machines that are NEW.

Comment: @TomTom It's probably a phone....

Comment: @MichaelHampton Well, given that there are now quad core phones coming - I hope you understand that this comment is not really sarcastic anymore.

Comment: Coming? The phone in my pocket is a quad core phone. :)

Comment: Sarcasm? @TomTom I think you might misunderstand Michael; your phone is the stuff of *legends* with the rest of us regulars :-)

Comment: Hehe. I understand. It still has no 4gb ram though. Sadly - they do not make blade-phones.... could use some blade center full of wonderphones.

Comment: @davidjhp What hardware is it, exactly?  Maybe you have an integrated video card stealing some RAM for itself?

Comment: It is a Dell Optiplex GX520, a cheap consumer box, I think it wasnt designed for a ton of RAM.

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# dmidecode | grep "Serial Number" <br>
        Serial Number: 7FSMYB1 <br>
        Serial Number: ..CN1374067403PN. <br>
        Serial Number: 7FSMYB1 <br>
        Serial Number: 00000000 <br>
        Serial Number: FFFFFFFF <br>

Answer (score 4):

Because it is about 3.5GB that it is detecting, I suspect strongly that you have installed a 32-bit OS on the server.  Some memory space is reserved for things like DMA.

You can verify this by using the `uname -m` command.  If it says something like `i686`, it's a 32 bit OS; if it says `x86_64` it's 64-bit.

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# uname -m
x86_64

Comment: In that case, you have a hardware failure, or a lack of CPU or system board support for more than 3.5GB of RAM.  Try updating the BIOS or EFI firmware perhaps, and failing that, swap out RAM modules.

Answer (score 3):

A better way

```
[root@localhost ~]# dmidecode --type 17 | grep Size
        Size: 2048 MB
        Size: 2048 MB
```

Comment: That tells you how much RAM is physically installed in the server. Good to know, no doubt. But it *fails* to tell you how much the OS actually *sees* and *uses* (which is *at least as important*).

Comment: Bloody well important information for determining whether you have a hardware or a software problem though.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you have a 32 bit operating system installed. Instead of re installing you could also look in to physical address extention

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingPAE

Gives help on Ubuntu. I'm sure you can find a similar method for the distro you have installed.

4gb should be plenty for your server unless you have large db or heavy io work planned

Comment: Why the down vote ?

Comment: Probably because your answer doesn't add much value over Falcon's answer

Comment: if its 32 bit enabling PAE will be a much easier process than reinstalling the entire OS

Comment: 1 - the OP did reply (admittedly after your answer) that it's a 64-bit OS.

Comment: 2 - PAE helps with RAM above 4 GB. It won't help you get RAM that's stuck in the DMA hole on a 32-bit system, or not accessible due to hardware limitations on the board.